# ¿Son válidas las respuestas que de alguna forma son auto promocionales?

Tags: discusión

Veo [está](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96693/como-separar-una-linea-por-columnas-con-determinado-tama%C3%B1o) pregunta, y es un problema para al que particularmente desarollé una herramienta, la cual está pública y bajo una licencia abierta. ¿Es válido o al menos no resulta reprobable, ofrecer una solución que involucra en este caso un desarrollo propio que bien podría considerarse como una auto-promoción?

Comment: Si la respuesta es autocontenida y útil, ¡publícala!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Primero de todo, la respuesta debe tener la calidad mínima exigida para el sitio como cualquier otra respuesta. Es importante que sea autocontenida como comenta @fedorqui.

Si la respuesta cumple con los requisitos de calidad y responde a la pregunta adecuadamente, la única duda es no cruzar la delgada y relativa línea entre querer ayudar a resolver el problema y el afán de autopromoción.

En el centro de ayuda, en el apartado de [¿Cuál es la conducta esperada de los usuarios?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)  encontramos una nota al respecto:

> **Evita la autopromoción**.
>
> La comunidad suele votar en contra de aportes con autopromoción y
>   marcarlos como spam. Contribuye respuestas relevantes y educadas, pero
>   cuando tengas respuestas sobre tu producto o sitio web deberás
>   divulgar tu afiliación en la respuesta.
>
> Si la gran mayoría de tus aportes incluyen menciones a tu producto or
>   sitio web, tal vez estas aquí por razones equivocadas. Nuestras
>   tarifas publicitarias son muy razonables; ponte en contacto con
>   nuestro equipo de ventas para mas información. Ofrecemos también
>   publicidades gratuitas para proyectos de código abierto y
>   organizaciones sin fines de lucro.

Parece pintarlo bastante mal, aunque no creo que tengas nunca problemas si tus intenciones son solamente ayudar y no de promocionar tu herramienta descaradamente. Esto muchas veces va a ser subjetivo, siempre que no estemos ante casos extremos, por ejemplo, un usuario que a la mínima que ve una pregunta relacionada con su herramienta coloca el enlace sin justificar ni explicar el cómo y el porqué de su utilidad en ese caso concreto, muchas veces copiando respuestas.

La clave está en **razonar porqué tu herramienta es particularmente adecuada para solventar ese problema** y **justificarlo** adecuadamente. Volviendo al concepto de autocontenida, siempre es importante explicar cómo se debe usar esa herramienta en ese caso concreto y ,de ser posible, agregar un código de ejemplo.

Otro tema importante es nunca ocultar o no comentar tu relación con la herramienta que recomiendas. En estos casos creo que la forma adecuada es dejar una nota al final de la respuesta **comentando tu relación con el proyecto** de forma clara. No ser transparente en estos casos puede ser negativo si alguien termina asociándote a la herramienta.

Además, **aclara que tu herramienta es de código abierto y libre**. Esto evitará bastantes prejuicios de muchos usuarios sobre tus intenciones.

Creo que haciendo lo anterior, especialmente justificar que tu respuesta es relevante para resolver el problema y solo recomendar la herramienta cuando esto ocurra, sin abusar de ello y siendo transparente en tus intenciones, la comunidad responderá positivamente en general y será considerado como un aporte positivo.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Aunque lo del código libre no lo veo claro. Es válido dar respuestas con herramientas de código no libre, por ejemplo el compilador de C++ de la corporación Microsoft. Y es válido que lo haga un empleado de la susodicha corporación.