# ¿Cuáles son las pautas para revisar?

Tags: soporte, colas-de-revisión, revisiones, propuesta-de-faq

#### Acerca de las colas de revisión

Las colas de revisión contienen publicaciones que posiblemente necesiten más acciones de la comunidad, como mejoras, cierre o eliminación. Al presentar estas publicaciones para ser revisados por pares, el sistema intenta conseguir un contenido de mayor calidad.

Algunas acciones de los usuarios, como sugerir una edición, reportar, votar para cerrar o votar para reabrir, o publicar por primera vez, pueden desencadenar la inclusión de una publicación en una cola de revisión. También hay publicaciones incluidas en las colas por parte de un algoritmo, como el contenido de *Respuestas tardías* y *Publicaciones de baja calidad*.

#### Reglas generales

- **Siempre lee toda la publicación que estás revisando**.
- **No corras**. Tómate el tiempo necesario para leer las publicaciones cuidadosamente.
- Si no te importa una publicación, simplemente haz clic en *Omitir* o *No estoy seguro*.
- Cuando necesites más contexto, abre el enlace de la publicación para ver la pregunta y todas las respuestas.
- La mayoría de las publicaciones pueden ser mejorados. Utiliza la opción *Editar* y edita a fondo.
- Si no estás seguro de cómo revisar una publicación (quizás esté fuera de tus áreas de especialización), omítela. Alguien que la entienda mejor lo revisará más tarde.

#### Pautas para colas de revisión específicas

(enlaces a respuestas a esta pregunta, en progreso; si estás traduciendo una, indícalo aquí para no solaparte con nadie)

- [Ediciones sugeridas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4104/)
- [Publicaciones de baja calidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4105/)
- [Primeras publicaciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4107/)
- [Respuestas tardías](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4894/83)
- Votos de cierre
- Votos de reapertura

<sub>Publicación basada en [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/) de Meta.SE.</sub>

Comment: Grandisimo trabajo y una publicación muy necesaria en mi opinión. Gracias por el curro :)

Comment: @Pikoh hay cuatro más por traducir, como siempre más manos son más que bienvenidas.

Comment: @fedorqui Gran aporte!

Answer (score 5):

### Pautas para revisar publicaciones de baja calidad

Las preguntas aparecen en la cola de mensajes de baja calidad, tanto por algoritmo como por [muy baja calidad o los "reportes de no es una respuesta" de los usuarios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190639/167534)<sub>en inglés</sub> (resumidamente: si recibe reportes de "no es una respuesta" o "muy baja calidad", una publicación se envía a esta cola).

### Flujo de trabajo básico

1. Comprueba si la publicación puede ser mejorada. Si puede elevar su calidad por encima del umbral de aceptabilidad, dale a **Editar**. Ten en cuenta que la edición dentro de la cola será un voto unilateral de *Se ve bien*, así que ten cuidado con las ediciones que solo hacen mejoras menores ("repintar el titanic a medida que se hunde"), pues estará provocando que la publicación se mantenga sin eliminar.
2. Si crees que una **respuesta** no responde a la pregunta o es incomprensible, dale a **Recomendar eliminación** (consulta los motivos comunes a continuación). Si no has dejado un comentario ni has dado +1 a un comentario ya existente, considera la posibilidad de elegir un comentario enlatado apropiado de la lista que aparece. Ten en cuenta que estos son solo comentarios enlatados, que no tienen ningún efecto adicional.

   Si crees que se debe cerrar una **pregunta**, dale a **Recomendar Cierre**.
3. Si nada de lo anterior aplica, elige **Se ve bien**.
     Esta es la elección correcta para las respuestas que están mal.
4. Si no estás seguro, dale a **Omitir**.

La mayoría de las veces, el revisor no debería necesitar experiencia en el tema para realizar la revisión.

Si tienes la reputación suficiente para emitir votos de cierre, *Recomendar Cierre* se convierte en *Cerrar* y emite un voto de cierre. Si puedes votar para eliminar, *Recomendar eliminación* se convierte en *Eliminar* y emite un voto de eliminación.

### Casos comunes

- [QA] **Spam o publicaciones ofensivas**: haz clic en el "enlace" a la publicación y repórtala. No elijas "recomiende eliminar" o "eliminar" en la cola.
- [Q] **Preguntas para cerrar**: *Recomendar Cerrar* abre el diálogo de cierre regular.
- [A] **Comentarios publicados como respuestas**: Esto es común entre los usuarios que no tienen la reputación de 50 necesaria para comentar, pero sienten que tienen algo útil que decir. No obstante, se recomienda eliminar. Si la respuesta contiene información útil pero así y todo no intenta responder, considera reportar para la atención del moderador y pedir que se convierta a comentario.
- [A] **Respuestas del tipo "Gracias", "También tengo este problema", así como diferentes preguntas publicadas como respuestas**: Se consideran ruido; Las respuestas deben ser respuestas reales. Recomienda eliminar y elegir el correspondiente comentario enlatado. Considera dejar un comentario individual para ayudar con la opción de hacer una nueva pregunta o para recomendar mejoras en una posible nueva pregunta.
- [A] **Respuestas que son solo un enlace**: Estas tienden a romperse si cambia la referencia vinculada. Se debe alentar a los usuarios a incluir las partes esenciales de la solución en el cuerpo de la respuesta.
  Ten en cuenta que [solo si la respuesta no tiene ningún valor sin el enlace, en realidad es una respuesta de solo enlace](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/255554)<sub>en inglés</sub>. También ten cuidado con el spam.

  - Si la información que hay en la página enlazada vale la pena, aún no aparece en otras respuestas y se puede editar, hazlo usando un bloque de citación (ten cuidado con las infracciones de derechos de autor).
  - Si el enlace es útil pero es inherentemente imposible editar la información (por ejemplo, si el enlace es a un video o imagen con derechos de autor), recomienda su eliminación. Si la respuesta sería un comentario útil, considera marcarla para la atención del moderador.
  - Si la información detrás del enlace es redundante respecto las respuestas existentes, recomienda su eliminación.
- [A] **Respuestas que no responden a la pregunta**: Si evalúas la respuesta como tal, primero verifica cuidadosamente si hay una falta de claridad en la pregunta que tú y el autor de la respuesta hayáis interpretado de manera diferente. De lo contrario recomienda su eliminación. Deja un comentario explicativo en ambos casos.
- [QA] **Galimatías**: Si la publicación claramente no pretende ser comprensible, recomiende su eliminación o el cierre ya que *no está claro lo que está preguntando*.
- [QA] **Publicaciones incomprensibles**: Mejora lo que puedas y deja un comentario para el autor. Vota para cerrar las preguntas ya que *no está claro lo que está preguntando*. Recomiende eliminar una respuesta, si lo que es comprensible no constituye una respuesta.
- [QA] **Formato, ortografía, estructura e idioma incorrectos**: Mejóralo o deja un comentario al autor. Si no hay otro problema y la publicación es comprensible, elige *Se ve bien*.
- [A] **Respuestas incorrectas e inútiles**: Si puedes solucionarlo sin hacer una edición intrusiva, hazlo. De lo contrario, deja un comentario explicando lo que está mal y, posiblemente, vota negativamente. Si no hay otro problema, elija *Se ve bien*.

*<sub>Respuesta original: [Guidelines for reviewing Low quality posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/).</sub>*

Answer (score 5):

## Directrices para revisar Primeras Publicaciones.

Ten en cuenta que el usuario es nuevo en el sitio, por lo que no conoce todos los entresijos de publicar una pregunta/respuesta. Es fundamental que ofrezcas unas pautas precisas y útiles.

Las preguntas ganan votos de acuerdo con su valor para los futuros usuarios, así como para el que pregunta, y de acuerdo con su capacidad de ser respondida. Una pregunta expresada simplemente con "¿Cómo puedo ..." sin aclarar las circunstancias, mostrar lo que el autor de la pregunta ha intentado o explicar los problemas que se está encontrando con lo que está probando actualmente no es una pregunta útil. Puedes mejorarla o votar para cerrarla. Las respuestas ganan votos de acuerdo con su utilidad, precisión y exhaustividad. Por ejemplo, una respuesta que consiste simplemente en un enlace no es útil en absoluto, y puedes marcarla como *No es una respuesta*.

---

### Motivos comunes para *Reportar/Cerrar/Eliminar*

#### Para preguntas

- Verifica el contexto, siempre que sea una pregunta debería tenerlo. El contexto alojado fuera del sitio (jsfiddle, el sitio de producción del que pregunta) es inadecuado. Los que quieren responder deben seguir un enlace para verlo, y es probable que cambie a lo largo de la vida útil de la pregunta, invalidando las respuestas dadas anteriormente.
- ¿Tiene la pregunta toda la información necesaria de una manera clara y concisa para proporcionar una respuesta autorizada, y está dentro de la temática del sitio?

  - Solicita la información que falta, para limitar el alcance de la pregunta, vuelva a redactar la pregunta para que se ajuste al alcance del sitio.
- ¿Te parece que ya has visto antes la misma pregunta?

  - Comprueba los comentarios; a veces señalan posibles duplicados
  - Ir al área de duplicados en la interfaz de usuario de reportes. Ver si hay alguna pregunta que sea similar.
- ¿La pregunta muestra algún indicio de investigación previa?
- Si proporcionan enlaces, evalúa si crees que la pregunta es spam. Una redacción similar a "Encontré una solución en `enlace` pero estoy buscando otras" puede ser un intento de promover `enlace`.

Reporte/Cierre:

- Preguntas duplicadas
- Preguntas que son solo una perorata del usuario.
- Una pregunta que es poco probable que ayude a un futuro usuario.
- Una pregunta que no es realmente una pregunta.
- Una pregunta que no puede ser contestada de manera inequívoca, como:

  - "¿Por qué la tecnología A no hace B?"
  - "¿Cuál es la mejor C para mi situación?"
  - "¿Cuándo se actualizará D y qué habrá de nuevo?"

#### Para respuestas

- ¿Es la publicación solo un enlace a la respuesta?
- Compruebe la existencia de código si proporcionan un enlace.
- ¿Es la respuesta en realidad una nueva pregunta?
- ¿Está la publicación respondiendo a la pregunta?

Reportar/Eliminar:

- Respuestas que solo contienen un enlace
- No relacionado con la pregunta.
- Alguien enviando un "gracias" a otro usuario.
- La publicación por parte del usuario original de una respuesta que es una copia exacta de la respuesta de otro usuario (similar a un agradecimiento)

No te centres en la respuesta real en sí. Céntrate en el formato y los modales del autor.

---

### Razones comunes para *Editar*

Después de determinar que la publicación será útil para la comunidad, intenta estar atento a los siguientes puntos:

1. Elimina los saludos, las declaraciones de urgencia, las garantías de haber buscado y probado cosas (especialmente si esas *cosas* no se aprecian en la pregunta por ninguna parte), promete apreciar la ayuda, solicita enlaces a tutoriales para alguien que acaba de empezar y similares.
2. No hay suficientes saltos de párrafo, o demasiados
3. Destaca la pregunta real, generalmente al principio o al final de la pregunta. Si debe estar en el medio, considera resaltarlo de alguna manera.
4. Falta de formato apropiado, como código no formateado, ya sea en línea o en bloque, o citas no identificadas adecuadamente como tales
5. Intentos de listas numeradas o con viñetas que no usan el marcado adecuado
6. Enlaces sin formato o enlaces "haga clic aquí" o "esto": el texto de la pantalla debe ser descriptivo, como *La documentación de MSDN* o *Un tutorial sobre excepciones*. Pasa el ratón por encima o sigue los enlaces para descartar el spam.
7. Imágenes o código alojado fuera del sitio: ábrelos en una nueva pestaña. Si son apropiados, incorpóralos a la pregunta. Para el código, es posible que necesites tener conocimientos sobre el lenguaje o la tecnología para saber qué traer. Si no lo sabes, puedes dejar un comentario para que el autor realice la edición.
8. Ortografía, gramática y puntuación, así como problemas con el espaciado, como el espacio antes de la coma.
9. Organización: muchos usuarios primerizos tienen 3-4 párrafos de charla, y después todo el código. Organiza las cosas correctamente para aumentar la legibilidad y la comprensión de la pregunta.
10. Un título que realmente describa la pregunta.
11. Eliminar cualquier tipo de grosería; Haz la publicación cortés y útil.

Después de arreglar todo eso, si aún falta más información (por ejemplo, qué sistema operativo se está utilizando), agrega un comentario solicitando que los detalles se editen en la pregunta. Un comentario a un nuevo usuario que solo hace una pregunta generalmente será respondido en los comentarios. Explícales como funciona el sitio.

---

### Razones comunes para *Votar Positivo*

Algunos revisores votan positivamente las publicaciones en la cola de revisión de Primeras Publicaciones que no tienen nada de malo en ellas, incluso si no lo harían si se la encontraran mientras utilizaban el sitio normalmente. La explicación habitual es que desean alentar a los recién llegados y hacer que se sientan bienvenidos. Esta es una razón válida para un voto a favor; si te sientes de esa manera, activa la publicación antes de hacer clic en "Terminado".

---

### Razones comunes para *Votar negativo*

Lo mejor que se puede hacer con las publicaciones incorrectas en la cola de revisión 
 de Primeras Publicaciones es mejorarlas. Lo siguiente mejor que puedes hacer es cerrarlos para que no acumulen respuestas hasta que la publicación sea mejorada. Votar negativamente pueden dar a entender a un nuevo usuario que no es bienvenido aquí. Dado que su reputación es generalmente 1, votar negativamente no reducirá su reputación; su impacto es totalmente emocional. Si deseas votar negativamente una primera publicación, pregúntate primero si no sería mejor cerrarla o corregirla.

*<sub>Respuesta Original: [Guidelines for reviewing First Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180030/)</sub>*

Comment: ¡Grande! Mil gracias. Y qué buena traducción, lo de _perorata_ queda genial. ¿Crees que valdría la pena enlazar también con [la página de Fiddles](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2446/83) y la de [¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/83) para dar pautas de comentarios a escribir por parte de los revisores?

Comment: @fedorqui pues si, me parece una buena idea la verdad.

Answer (score 3):

### Pautas para revisar ediciones sugeridas

#### Flujo de trabajo básico

1. Revisa las diferencias entre la publicación original y la edición sugerida, así como el resumen de edición sobre las diferencias.
2. Comprueba si hay alguna razón para aprobar la edición como está. Si encuentras alguna, dale a ***Aprobar***.
3. Verifica si la edición sugerida está completa. Si hay algo más que editar, dale a ***Mejorar Edición***.
4. Si existe evidencia clara de que la edición empeora la publicación o que no resuelve los problemas críticos, dale a ***Rechazar*** o ***Rechazar y editar***.
5. En caso contrario, dale a ***Omitir***.

#### Razones comunes para darle a *Aprobar*

- Ediciones que intentan agregar una aclaración a una respuesta, como "esto no funciona en Windows 8", o los apéndices a la publicación deben ser aprobados.
- Ediciones que corrigen errores gramaticales o que hacen que la publicación sea más fácil de entender.
- Ediciones que incluyen información adicional que solo se encuentra en los comentarios.
- Ediciones que incluyen actualizaciones a medida que la publicación envejece, o que corrigen errores menores.
- Ediciones que agregan recursos o enlaces relevantes.

#### Razones comunes para darle a *Rechazar*

- Ediciones que introducen formato (código, negrita o cursiva) que no tienen sentido o que no añaden nada. Rechaza como *ninguna mejora en absoluto* o *causa daño*, según el caso.
- Ediciones que cambian la explicación o el código de una respuesta a una alternativa completamente diferente. Si la edición propuesta es una mejora de la respuesta actual, debes poder verificarlo: ve a la pregunta y verifica que la respuesta aún tenga el mismo efecto deseado que antes.
- Las ediciones que modifican el código o corrigen los errores tipográficos del código **en una pregunta**, a menos que claramente no invaliden la pregunta, deben rechazarse ya que *claramente están en conflicto con la intención del autor*.
- Ediciones que plagian contenido de una fuente externa sin la debida atribución. Recházalos como *causa daño* y escribe una explicación. (**¡Siempre verifica si se está plagiando de sitios típicos como Wikipedia cuando se crea una etiqueta wiki / extracto!**). Para las etiquetas wikis y extractos, hay un motivo especial *contenido copiado*, así que directamente úsalo.
- Ediciones que agregan contenido que no pertenece (por ejemplo, "gracias de antemano", "por favor, ayúdame", "SOLUCIONADO" en el título). Recházalas como *ninguna mejora en absoluto*.
- Ediciones que agregan etiquetas irrelevantes.
- Ediciones que cambian las URL para enlazar a contenido no relacionado deben rechazarse como *spam o vandalismo*. La página de revisión mostrará automáticamente la fuente de Markdown cada vez que se cambie un enlace.

**Verifica explícitamente los cambios en la URL**: Esta es una forma fácil de introducir spam, por lo que no debes asumir que la actualización de un enlace sea correcta sin verificarlo. Si se cambia algún enlace, el sistema mostrará automáticamente la vista de Markdown de forma predeterminada. Sin embargo, ten en cuenta que debes verificar que el formato sea correcto al ver la salida renderizada.

**Revise el resumen de edición antes de rechazar**: Ocasionalmente, un usuario puede haber proporcionado información en un comentario u otra respuesta que no se puede ver en la pantalla de revisión de edición, por lo que el editor trae ese contenido a la publicación. Esto debe ser mencionado en el resumen de edición. Puedes hacer clic en el enlace de la pregunta (probablemente es mejor abrirlo en una nueva pestaña) para ver el contexto completo.

**Sabes de qué trata la publicación siempre ayuda**: A veces, una edición corrige errores menores que obviamente fueron escritos a mano por el respondedor (los errores tipográficos en las preguntas solo deben corregirse si eso no invalida la pregunta). Es un reto saber la diferencia entre un error tipográfico y un cambio real si no conoces el tema o el contexto de la publicación. Por ejemplo, en Perl, un solo carácter puede cambiar todo el significado de una línea. En C ++, cambiar `==` a `=` también puede tener un impacto dramático. No siempre es necesario entender el contenido de una edición para revisarla, ya que las ediciones sugeridas pueden consistir en cambiar el formato sin cambiar el significado, pero si no estás seguro, dale a **omitir** la edición y déjalo a quien sepa.

Para obtener información específica sobre la revisión de ediciones de etiquetas de wiki, consulta [esta respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173838/how-do-i-review-tag-wiki-edits-for-new-tags/173871#173871)<sub>en inglés</sub> a [How do I review tag wiki edits for new tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173838/how-do-i-review-tag-wiki-edits-for-new-tags)<sub>en inglés</sub>.

Ten en cuenta que si la publicación es wiki de comunidad, el autor renuncia a la autoría y cambiar el significado no es tan importante como mejorar la publicación.

*<sub>Respuesta original: [Guidelines for reviewing Suggested Edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539/209901/)</sub>*

Answer (score 2):

### Orientaciones para revisar respuestas tardías

Las respuestas situadas en la cola de revisión de respuestas tardías también pueden ser primeras publicaciones ofrecidas por nuevos usuarios; de modo que conviene que aplique, sobre ellas, todos los pasos recomendados para revisar las primeras publicaciones.

### Elementos a tener en cuenta

1. Muchas respuestas tardías pueden ser **spam** o *autobombo* publicitario.
   Típicamente, un usuario agrega dentro de una o varias respuestas expresiones del tipo "**Mi producto**" o "El producto xxx" hace esto u ofrece tal o cual funcionalidad y agrega **un enlace**; se debe contrastar
   con los criterios ofrecidos en [¿Son válidas las respuestas que de alguna forma son auto promocionales?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2723/91033).
   Si la respuesta se ajusta a tales criterios,
   agregue un comentario indicando que es pertinente, para reducir la probabilidad de que sea marcada como *spam* por otro usuario.
   En caso contrario, agregue un comentario indicando el caso y solicite su
   edición. Adicionalmente, considere la posibilidad de mantener abierta la pregunta en una pestaña, de modo que luego de algunas horas pueda regresar a ella y **marcarla como spam** si su comentario no tuvo efecto.
2. Muchas respuestas tardías no son respuestas
   Los usuarios que carecen de [privilegios para dejar comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) suelen "responder" ya sea para hacer una nueva pregunta ampliando la original o pedir una aclaración al autor. O, simplemente dejan enlaces pertinentes como respuesta.
   Debe marcarse indicando que no es una respuesta y dejar un comentario al autor de la misma indicándole que el lugar correcto para ese tipo de "respuestas" es el de los comentarios (aunque todavía no tengan privilegios para hacerlos).
   También ocurre que muchos usuarios confunden Stack Exchange con un foro tradicional, donde está bien publicar respuestas de agradecimiento o nuevas preguntas con una respuesta.  En estos casos conviene dejar un comentario adecuado y marcar que no son respuestas.
3. Pertinencia de las respuestas
   Es muy importante verificar que las respuestas *resuelvan* lo preguntado, que posean relevancia. Si no conoce suficientemente el tópico evite cualquier acción más allá de hacer ajustes de formato. (-Yo sugiero que la omita para que no salga de la cola de revisión y pueda pasar a manos de alguien que sepa).
4. Además de votar o reportar, se puede dejar un comentario. O si ya existe otro que abarque la situación a comentar vote ese comentario.

---

### Razones típicas para reportar o eliminar

- Spam o contenido grosero o abusivo.
- Contenidos bien intencionados que **no son respuestas efectivas**, de personas que aún deben aprender cómo funciona nuestro sitio.

---

### Razones típicas para votar a favor

- La respuesta resuelve la pregunta y tiene buena calidad.

*<sub>Respuesta original: [Guidelines for reviewing Late Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031/708440) (traducción libre)</sub>*

Comment: @Pollo Me gustan las sugerencias. Parecen muy pertinentes. Esperemos un par de días, para hacer efectivos los cambios, de modo que se pueda incorporar otros ajustes en una sola tarea.

Comment: @Pollo De momento hice los ajustes 2, 3 y 4, Para el 1 sigo en duda porque no se indica un procedimiento o un paso a paso; en cuanto a 5: **reportar como no es respuesta** invita a simplemente borrar, mientras que al pedir intervención (que es casi lo mismo) debes dejar una nota del por qué y puedes invitar a mover a comentarios. En cuanto a 6 se me pasó hacer el cambio pues pienso en la alternativa **denunciar**. Y, 7 no lo entendí (podrías cambiarlo tu mismo)

Comment: @Pollo (5) suficiente ilustración. Quito la sugerencia. (6) No había caído en cuenta simplemente por consistencia debe ser **reportar** (7) ¿Debo marcar como wiki? - No se me da. Me parece que para algo que sólo ha sido visto por dos personas y no cuenta con consenso es pretencioso hacerlo.

Comment: Gracias @Pollo. Has sido de gran ayuda. Cuando haya nuevos aportes, de gente con más solvencia, lo marco como wiki. Por ahora me produce algo parecido a vergüenza

Comment: ¿Cómo que vergüenza? Es una publicación excelente. Por cierto, en general usamos el tuteo en las publicaciones de este tipo, pero tampoco es norma

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' La vergüenza es por tomarme la atribución de convertir en wiki de la comunidad algo que aún no ha sido revisado.

Comment: Listo. Entonces la paso a wiki