# ¿Es correcto revertir una edición, si es que esta ya ha sido aprobada?

Tags: discusión, ediciones-sugeridas

Acabo de obtener el privilegio de poder revisar las `Publicaciones de baja calidad` y las `Ediciones sugeridas`, cada vez que paso por las **Revisiones**, cualquiera sea, tomo el tiempo de leer y ver que tanto aporta la edición a la pregunta o respuesta original.

Me he topado con esta [propuesta de edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/191046) en donde claramente, se ve que solo es para añadir un problema diferente a la respuesta, en lugar de formular una [pregunta nueva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), de acuerdo a lo que leí:

> Esta edición se aparta de la intención original de la publicación.
>   Incluso aquellas ediciones que implican grandes cambios deben
>   esmerarse para preservar los objetivos del propietario de la
>   publicación.

Concuerda con lo que trata de hacer la edición, pero me he encontrado que se ha aprobado de igual manera con dos votos a favor, por lo mismo al parecer no se respetaron las [pautas para las correcciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4103/cu%C3%A1les-son-las-pautas-para-revisar)

O la [siguiente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/190989) que se ha editado la pregunta, para facilitar la lectura o que se entendiera mejor la pregunta, pero eso he visto muchas veces que debe ser el OP quién debe de hacerlo, me he fijado además que el OP no aparece como que aprobó la edición.

A diferencia de [esta edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/190983), que al igual que las otras ha intentado de agregar algo adicional, que difiere con la publicación original y por ende se ha rechazado.

En la pauta para revisar, pone:

> **No corras.** Tómate el tiempo necesario para leer las publicaciones
>   cuidadosamente.

Y creo que esto no se está llevando a cabo correctamente.

Ambas las he editado nuevamente, para que estas vuelvan a su estado original, ¿es correcto lo que hice?

Comment: Bien por vos y hacer notar estas cosas. Algunos de los usuarios que aceptaron esas correcciones no se porque lo hicieron. Hablaremos con los mismos.

Comment: me parece perfecto este aporte

Comment: Interesante caso el que comentas, pues la sugerencia de edición es una respuesta del autor de la pregunta a la respuesta de @gbi, por lo que probablemente lo mejor sería que se incorporara a la pregunta original

Comment: @fedorqui claro o si es que fuera necesario realizar una pregunta nueva, llevo en el sitio más o menos un año, y esto es lo que he sabido siempre, por eso que aprobaran ambas ediciones me hizo bastante ruido, así que decidí comentarlo quizás me estaba equivocando yo

Comment: joooo x.x! mis disculpas, leí mal, esa edición debió ser rechazada, pensé que el OP estaba agregando mayor información a la pregunta, cuando en realidad, era a la respuesta o.oU

Comment: @fredyfx Eso es imposible, si agregara información solo editaría la pregunta, no haría una edición sugerida... A no ser que tenga bloqueado editar publicaciones y no le quede más remedio. que sugerir una edición a su propia pregunta.