# Cuando todas las revisiones son "No se requiere ninguna acción"

Tags: soporte, moderación, revisiones, usuarios

¿Qué hacer cuando veo un usuario que me parece que está revisando mal intencionalmente?
- ... y aclaro antes que levanté un reporte personalizado que fue rechazado.

Resulta que vi una pregunta que en mi opinión estaba en estado deplorable, sin comentarios ni nada. Yo no tenía nada pendiente en cola de primeras publicaciones y me pregunté cómo podría haber pasado. La respuesta fue evidente al ver las revisiones del usuario que ya había revisado esa pregunta:

> [image: roboreviews "No se requiere ninguna acción"]

... y así por lo menos a lo largo de 15 páginas (hasta que me aburrí de mirar).

Es un usuario con más re 3000 revisiones hechas. Entre las últimas 10 revisiones encontré:

- una pregunta en inglés
- una respuesta tardía que es solamente un link
- una pregunta de 1 línea con una captura de pantalla del código
- una pregunta que muestra solamente la última línea del stack trace sin mostrar siquiera la línea de código en donde se genera

Pensé en dejarle un comentario al usuario, pero me pareció que iba a generar más una pelea que una resolución del tema porque según mi punto de vista esto es algo que claramente está haciendo de forma intencional, lejos de ser un error u omisión. Entonces fui por un reporte personalizado a un moderador sobre una de las preguntas que había revisado este usuario con el texto:

> Hola. ¿Podrían ver las revisiones de `https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/ <<<id>>> / <<<nombre>>> ?tab=activity&sort=reviews` ? Me parece que se está pasando con roboreviews. Esto está perjudicando a las preguntas que quedan sin una revisión consciente y que siguen más tiempo con baja calidad hasta que se detectan.
>
> > (*) datos reemplazados intencionalmente

pero fue rechazado como:

> un moderador revisó tu reporte, pero no encontró ninguna evidencia para apoyarlo.

No sé si fue que el moderador le pifió nomás, que yo tengo algún concepto equivocado, o si en realidad era otra la forma correcta de encararlo. Tampoco sé si debiera publicar qué usuario es y mostrar los casos para discutirlos, ustedes me dirán, aunque no me parece la mejor opción.

¿Hay que hacer algo? ¿Qué?

Comment: Me parece raro que puedan ser tantas páginas. Alguna vez, en una de las colas que de revisión que tuve a mano, no sabía que hacer en un par de preguntas y marqué la opción **no se necesita ninguna acción** y el sistema me regañó (merecidamente) por mediocre, **indicándome que debía prestar mayor atención**. Eso me hace pensar que la calificación del usuario que hace eso deba ser alta, pues el sistema no lo tiene en prueba.

Comment: No se si exista alguna guía para colaborar en las colas de revisión. Y, aprovecho para enunciar mi duda: cuando no se del tema de la pregunta y no es evidentemente mala **marco ignorar** en la esperanza de que quede en cola para que **la revise alguien que sepa** ¿Se mantiene en cola dicha pregunta?

Comment: @quevedo (1) pensá que este es un extremo, con un caso de una pregunta ***en inglés*** a la que le puso que no se requería ninguna acción, no creo que sea una equivocación, sino una forma intencional de sumar revisiones rápidas para alguna medalla. (2) Mi preferida es https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4103/193460, pero si queda algo por cubrir, se puede preguntar acá en Meta (3) Sí, claro, al *Omitir*, no estás tomando una acción y queda en cola para que otro revise

Comment: gracias por tus observaciones. El enlace me ha resultado muy útil y lo marque como favorito.

Comment: Repórtalo a los moderadores para que revisen. Pueden enviar un mensaje al usuario, bloquearlo de revisar, etc

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' claro, fue lo que pensé, pero me rechazaron el reporte. Por eso no entiendo qué es lo que estaba mal.

Comment: Uy perdona, no leí esa parte en tu pregunta, leí demasiado rápido. Pues entonces hiciste bien trayéndolo a Meta y me parece que los moderadores se colaron al rechazártelo. Bien descubierto, revisores así no hacen ningún bien al sitio

Comment: Si es que fue eso, me quedo súper tranquilo sabiendo que todo cuadra de nuevo, hasta no tendría problema en eliminar la pregunta para no generar más ruido.. Todos somos humanos y bastantes reportes deben tener para limpiar

Comment: Pollo y @quevedo sobre la pregunta que enlazáis ([¿Cuáles son las pautas para revisar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4103/83)), faltan tres respuestas por traducir, quien quiera puede ponerse a ello.

Comment: Vamos a revisar este tema. De todas maneras creo que lo que has hecho ha sido totalmente correcto: flag a los moderadores y si hay dudas, venir a meta. Trataremos de darte una respuesta lo antes posible.

Comment: ¿Dónde puedo ver las revisiones de un usuario o quién revisó una pregunta?

Comment: @CandidMoe Revisiones de un usuario en su perfil (Actividad > Todas las acciones > Revisiones). Estas son las mías: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/193460/pollo?tab=activity&sort=reviews ....... Quién revisó una pregunta en el timeline de la pregunta (botón abajo de votos). Este es el timeline de tu primer respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/368191/timeline (donde podés hacer click para ver la revisión de primera publicación que tuvo)

Comment: Hola @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' estoy terminando un borrador de **respuestas tardías** ¿Lo propongo, agregándolo dentro de las respuestas a la pregunta? o, ¿hay algún otro sitio para postular la traducción?

Comment: @quevedo allí mismo está perfecto. Entre todos podemos ir puliendo, así que publica sin miedo :)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Acabo de postear el borrador de traducción. Te agradecería mucho si **lo maquillas**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno la cosa fue asi..

Rechace tu reporte, porque lo lei, y no lo entendi... o en realidad, lo entendi mal...

Entendi, que el usuario estaba editando la publicacion varias veces sin agregarle contenido... y eso fue lo que rechace...

No entendi que era otro usuario en otra cola que estaba haciendo eso.

Todo el equipo de moderacion agradece infinitamente la ayuda de todos los usuarios. y gracias por hacernos ver estas cosas...

Yo particularmente, me disculpo por no haber entendido tu reporte...

Ya tomaremos las medidas del caso...

Comment: Ah bueno, todo bien, olvidate!!! La verdad me preocupaba si yo lo estaba viendo equivocado. Una pifiada nomás al leer es algo normal! Por mi parte, si tengo otro reporte personalizado, voy a tratar de escribir más concreto. Es difícil con pocos caracteres, pero creo que fue porque no me animaba a afirmar rotundamente de qué se trataba. Mil gracias, en serio, por mirarlo y responder sin vueltas!!! Espero que ayude a que haya mejor calidad en preguntas nuevas.

Comment: Y al mismo tiempo, lo que menos me interesa es dejar esto publicado... Un pifie no creo que le sirva como pregunta de Meta a nadie. Si querés borrar la publicación, me parece perfecto.

Comment: no hay ningun problema.. somos humanos y me puedo equivocar como todos... y no tengo problema en decir me equivoque... y mas, si hasta fue un error honesto porque nada mejor que alguien detecte algo extraño y nos los haga llegar... a veces tratar de avisarnos por el chat (y podemos armar uno privado los mods) es mejor... pero esta correcto hacerlo notar... la comunidad somos todos...

Comment: Totalmente, pero acordátelo para cuando el pifie esté de mi lado, jajaja ;-) Tenés razón, no se me ocurrió buscar un término medio como el chat. Lo tengo en cuenta ahora.